# How to build Android Archive Library(AAR) with Android Build Tools?

Tags: android, aar

I want to build aar files but I dont have Android Studio as my computer cannot run it.

How to build it from command line using the raw build tools; no gradle included?

The steps to build apk are:

1. generate R.java file with (aapt).
2. compile src files including R.java with (javac)
3. dex classes with (dx)
4. package, sign, align.

I understand that aar manifest(s) are not compiled to binary format. Thus the first step may not work when creating aar libs.

Please, I am begging, how to, the steps to creating with the build tools.

Answer (score 2):

`./gradlew <moduleName>:bundle<build_variant>Aar`

//for example

`./gradlew app:bundleReleaseAar`

Comment: It is nice that you gave me an example but 1. I know nothing about gradle; 2. I am already working with direct build tools to build my apps, and just need to apply them to build AAR

Comment: Shoud be accept as answer, you can type this in terminal android studio @user13947194

Comment: @IsmaRekathakusuma I clearly pointed out that I am not interested in using gradle.